# How to creating an application launcher Desktop icon for Android Studio Emulator in Ubuntu?

Tags: android, android-emulator, ubuntu-16.04

I want to know is it possible for creating a application launcher icon for **Emulator**(Android Studio) with a specific version of Android Device and OS like ***Nexus_4_API_27*** in **Ubuntu 16.04**.

If you know please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I want to create a launcher so that i can start emulator easily without starting android studio.

Comment: Is it for "Start the Emulator from the Command Line"? I want to make a launcher to open up the emulator with an android device and an android OS.

Comment: @pskink, I mean that I will dual click on a icon and the android Nexus_4_API_27 emulator will open.

Comment: Please see the @Alexandru Sandu's answer, you will be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, yes. You can open the emulator with certain commands from the command line and you can create a script that will run those commands automatically and then link it to your desktp.

To create an executable script with a shortcut on the desktop: https://askubuntu.com/questions/299052/how-to-execute-sh-script-from-a-desktop-shortcut

And in the script you need to set the commands for opening the emulator which you can find here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html

I don't have an ubuntu machine right now so i can't help you more but you should be able t get it going from here.

Answer (score 6):

Go to the Android Studio Application menu bar. Go to **tools** then click **Desktop Entry** and it will be added on your applications menu.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully above solution would be working fine.
Here is **another and generic** way to create desktop icon for Ubuntu application.

Let take an example of **robo**-
Run following command from the terminal
`sudo nano /usr/share/applications/robo.desktop`
and paste the code

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=Robo
Icon=/opt/robo-{robo-version}/bin/robo.png
# Ex- /usr/local/bin/robo3t/robo3t-1.4.3-linux-x86_64-48f7dfd/bin
Exec="/opt/robo-{robo-version}/bin/robo"
# Ex- /usr/local/bin/robo3t/robo3t-1.4.3-linux-x86_64-48f7dfd/bin/robo3t
Comment=Robomongo desktop entry
Categories=Development;
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
```

> Note- **Icon** should be the icon.png path which we want to display and **Exec** must be the exact executable file path.

Now, we can find the icon in application launcher menu by search for **robo**.
Similarly we can create desktop icon for any application in Ubuntu.